# How to apply CSS to a dropdown selection list?

Tags: html, css, forms, list

I am currently playing around with a form that I have created. The form has three inputs the first two of which are dropdown lists and the last input an ordinary text field. This is my HTML code for the form:

```
<div id="form-main">
    <div id="form-div">

        <form class="form" id="form1">
            <p class="sendingfrom">
                <select name="sendingfrom">
                    <option value="africa">Africa</option>
                    <option value="USA">USA</option>
                    <option value="Australia">Fiat</option>
                    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p class="sendingto">
                <select name="sendingto">
                    <option value="africa">Africa</option>
                    <option value="USA">USA</option>
                    <option value="Australia">Fiat</option>
                    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                </select>
            </p>

            <p class="weight">
                <input name="weight" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Weight" id="weight" />
            </p>

        </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

I would like to customize the look of the form through the use of CSS. However it seems like my CSS coding isn't affecting the visual look of the dropdown boxes except for the "weight" text box. This is the CSS code that I have applied to my form:

```css
#form-div {
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
    left: 471px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: -260px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    top: -11px;
}

.feedback-input {
    color:#3c3c3c;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 0;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.feedback-input:focus{
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0;
    border: 3px solid #34495e;
    color: #34495e;
    outline: none;
    padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
}

.focused{
    color:#30aed6;
    border:#30aed6 solid 3px;
}

input:hover, textarea:hover, 
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    background-color:#bdc3c7;
}
```

I am sure that I am missing something out on the CSS coding but I am not exactly sure how to rectify this problem. I am new to HTML and CSS and I am trying to learn my way into both these areas. I apologize if this issue seems too trivial. It would be much appreciated if someone could help me rectify the error that I seem to be experiencing.

Comment: the class you assigned for your select , is not defined in your css .. even you have done this at many place. I think you don't know about classes in css..

Comment: I would suggest you learn some basics of css first. You can go to w3schools.com as a novice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the tag via the CSS.

Looking at your CSS you are not doing that for the `select` elements.

1. First (and so that it is simple) apply a class to the elements
   (example: `class="my-select"`)

   in context:

   ```
   <select name="sendingfrom" class="my-select">
       <option value="africa">Africa</option>
       <option value="USA">USA</option>
       <option value="Australia">Fiat</option>
       <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
   </select>
   ```
2. Then target it via the CSS:

   ```
   .my-select {
       color: red;
       font-size: 14px;
   }
   ```

Comment: this doesn't do anything: [http://jsfiddle.net/w7amD/](http://jsfiddle.net/w7amD/)

Comment: @webeno using Safari? with firefox it does (or Internet Explorer).

Comment: I'm using Chrome on iMac (note: I'm not the OP, just a curious SO user) ;)

Comment: ...looks like you have to at least set the border too in order for any styling to work ar all...

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/sNwrs/1548/)

[the `pointer-events` property.](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/custom-select-drop-downs-with-css3/)

overlay an element over the native drop down arrow and then disallow pointer events on it.

[dev.W3.org](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#pointer-events)

works well in WebKit and Gecko.

html

```
    <!--[if !IE]> -->
    <div class="notIE">
        <!-- <![endif]-->
        <label />
        <select name="sendingfrom" class="my-select">
            <option value="africa">Africa</option>
            <option value="USA">USA</option>
            <option value="Australia">Fiat</option>
            <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
        </select>
        <!--[if !IE]> -->
    </div>
    <!-- <![endif]-->
```

css

```
select {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 3px 5px 5px;
    width: 150px;
    outline: none;
    color: blue;
    border: 1px solid #C8BFC4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px #ddd8dc;
    background-color: #fff;
}

/*target non IE 9 and IE 10 as pointer events are not supported*/
     .notIE label:after {
        content:'';
        width: 23px;
        height: 23px;
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        top: 4px;
        right: 4px;
        background: url(http://www.jewellerynetasia.com/portals/0/Images/social-network-service/google-plus.png) no-repeat right center white;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

/*target IE 9 and IE 10:*/
 @media screen and (min-width:0\0) {
    .notIE label:after {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

[border-radius is supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsOgq.png) as in image.

[source](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/custom-select-drop-downs-with-css3/)

Comment: any explanation you may want to add as to what you did and why you did it? by the way, not all of your styling got styled for me for example (OSX / Chrome), eg. `border-radius` isn't applied at all...

Answer (score 0):

Styling the `select` element is a tricky one. The behaviour, depending on what exactly you would like to do it, may differ from browser to browser.

One thing I realized throughout my testings is that you need to set the border property on `select` (or give it a class or id and refer to it), at least.

```css
select {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

But it still isn't going to accept everything (mostly color, height, width and border color only), and it won't be applied to the list of selections, or at least not in every browser.

I suggest you have a look at article [Dropdown Default Styling](http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/) discussing this in detail.

Comment: This way of styling will affect all select statement of one's page.